# Unable to add Tasks to any Lists - Quota Exceeded Error

Tags: google-tasks-api, google-tasks

I have recently encountered a problem with adding new tasks to Google-Tasks.

Both the Google Calendar integration (in any browser) and the Google Tasks App (on Android - Galaxy S9+) report an error whenever I try to add a new task.

On Google Calendar I get the error message:

> "Reverting to the latest state because there was a problem."

On the Google Tasks App I get the error message:

> "Unknown Server Error. Please try again later"

neither of which is very informative about how to solve the problem.

I did some further investigation via the Google-Tasks-API and found that I can still delete and modify tasks, but whenever I try to insert a new task into a list I get the following 403 error message from the API:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "quotaExceeded",
    "message": "Quota Exceeded"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Quota Exceeded"
 }
}
```

However, I checked my Google-Tasks API quotas at:
    https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/quotas
and I don't seem to be anywhere near any of the usages limits, so I don't really understand why I am getting this error message.

I've been using Google Tasks successfully for several years, including using the Google-Tasks-API to manage bulk updates, but have not changed any of my set-up recently. Is it possible I have stumbled into some global limit on the number of tasks permitted, or a limit on the number of tasks per list? I do have quite a lot of long-running tasks (I have a list to track dev ideas for some software that I maintain).

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I use Google Tasks to organise almost every aspect of my work-life and being without this is rather disruptive to my productivity.

It is rather frustrating that this issue seems to be affecting my normal day-to-day use of Google Calendar Tasks and the Google-Tasks App (I could have coped if it were just my script that uses the API that was not working).

Comment: Are you using a service account? It would be helpful to see your code?

Comment: No, this is just a personal account.
My code is little more than the Ruby quickstart code you can find at:
    <https://developers.google.com/tasks/quickstart/ruby>

The call that generates the error is a simple:
    service.insert_task(list_id,some_task)
where list_id is definitely the correct ID for my list (I can update existing tasks via the API) and some_task has been created with the expected params (title, due and notes).

What's wierd is that Google Tasks via the website or app is also not working.

Comment: Sometimes a server error can temporarily occur due to server-side problems from Google's side. If the problem still persists - can you provide the exact request that gives you this error?

Comment: While investigating this issue further I dug into the response from the Google Tasks integration with Google Calendar and found the following:
"Storage limit reached: Task creation failed because you exceeded the maximum number of 100000 tasks per account."

So that explains the problem. Now I just need to work out how to fix this (deleting tasks does not seem to help)

Comment: See here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en Basically, you have to delete events and tasks and still wait until your quota replenishes.

Comment: Yes, that would seem to be the "solution".
I guess I play the waiting game now... 
(I'm assuming that the Tasks need to be cleared off of some back-up server before Google will acknowledge that I am back under my quota).

Comment: Just in case anyone runs into the same issue, you have to wait about 1 month from the deletion of your tasks before you see any effect on your quota.